# How can I remove the word ".rs" from a string using VimScript?

Tags: linux, vim

How can I remove the word ".rs" from a string using VimScript?

`:! "rustc" a:arq
:! "./" a:arq`

however this second paragraph is not the compiled file, and it causes an error while performing my function. I wanted to remove this ".rs" so that it will execute the file after compilation (which by default is the same name as the compiled file)

Answer (score -1):

```
:! "./" . substitute(a:arq, '\.rs$', '', '')
```

Replace '.rs' at the end of the `a:arq` with an empty string.

See http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#substitute()